# Facebook App Iframe set auto grow

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

We are calling FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() before end of the body tag in our app. But it is not working. Where should we put the autogrow to make sure it gets called

Comment: Have you enabled Canvas Height to Settable in app settings on developer.

Comment: Is this when you are looking at the Canvas Page, or a Page Tab?

Comment: this is in the advanced settings -> canvas settings.  It needs to not be fluid, set it to a number for autogrow to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just after you call the FB.init() function is where I usually put it.  That's usually inside of the fbAsyncInit function.

Answer (score 0):

It should be included after this area:

```
FB.init({
//SETTINGS HERE
});
```

If you believe you have everything set up correctly and it still isn't working, make sure you have the correct doctype set.  That can cause it not to work in versions of IE.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope that helps...